# Among Fusion Charts,High Charts,EXTJs Charts better

Tags: extjs, highcharts, fusioncharts

Among Fusion Charts,High Charts,EXTJs Charts  which one is best charts and why it is best and why it is best chan any one give suggitation please.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to define "best overall", unless you objectively define what you want your charting library to do.

For example, FusionCharts offers both Flash and JavaScript charts with the widest coverage of chart types (90+ chart types, 900+ maps, including 3D charts), whereas HighCharts has this nifty stock chart that lets you scroll through a large data set with zooming/panning, and Sencha touch is better suited for mobile applications. FusionCharts has domain specific charts for finance, statistics, networks.  HighCharts v3 recently launched newer chart types. Both FusionCharts and HighCharts allow you to render the chart at server-side using PhantomJS. Both have thousands of customers globally.

Comment: Thanks for yur reply Pallav